# How can I use the number of found rows assigned on a variable and use it in INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the number of results on my temporary table, so I created a query, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp_sales_negative; -- Selected all columns on my temporary table

SET @limit = (SELECT FOUND_ROWS()); -- Set a variable assignment named 'limit'
```

The above query works fine and I got the correct number of resulting rows, but when I use the variable name in this query:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_credit_memo_receivables(credit_memo_id, amount)
SELECT id, amount FROM credit ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT @limit;
```

It prompts a syntax error on `@limit` part. Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql for this. To use dynamic sql you have to do this in a stored procedure.

Create the procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_limit()
BEGIN
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tmp_sales_negative;
SET @limit = (SELECT FOUND_ROWS());
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO tmp_credit_memo_receivables(credit_memo_id, amount)
SELECT id, amount FROM credit ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?;';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @limit;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then execute it with

```
CALL sp_limit();
```